# Ocultar mensajes de error en objeto Dashboard

Tags: genexus

Alguien sabe si es posible ocultar los mensajes de error que tira el objeto Dashboard al ejecutar un query?
Me interesan que se vean en desarrollo pero no en producción.

Por ejemplo:

```
Error: java.sql.SQLException: Error al convertir el tipo de datos nvarchar a numeric. at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:365) at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2781) at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2224) at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.isDataInResultSet(TdsCore.java:792) at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsResultSet.<init>(JtdsResultSet.java:146) at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQLQuery(JtdsStatement.java:424) at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:693) at com.genexus.db.driver.GXDBMSsqlserver.executeQuery(GXDBMSsqlserver.java:17) at com.genexus.db.driver.GXPreparedStatement.executeQuery(GXPreparedStatement.java:196) at com.genexus.db.ForEachCursor.postExecute(ForEachCursor.java:183) at com.genexus.db.DataStoreProvider.execute(DataStoreProvider.java:279) at com.genexus.db.DataStoreProvider.execute(DataStoreProvider.java:204) at qviewer.services.gxpl_DBAccess.ExecuteSQL(gxpl_DBAccess.java:95) at qviewer.services.gxpl_DBAccess.ExecuteSQL(gxpl_DBAccess.java:225) at qviewer.services.Sdtgxpl_DBAccess.executesql(Sdtgxpl_DBAccess.java:67) at qviewer.services.data.recordset.gxpl_getrecordsetquery.privateExecute(gxpl_getrecordsetquery.java:101) at qviewer.services.data.recordset.gxpl_getrecordsetquery.execute_int(gxpl_getrecordsetquery.java:75) at.....
```

Estoy con Gx16 U11 + Java + SQLServer
Gracias desde ya